# How to return video duration from custom object constructor function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, constructor, scope, return, html5-video

I'm trying to obtain the video duration inside a custom video constructor function. Is this a problem of scope? How would I go on and do this efficiently? The video is displayed correctly, I just can't seem to access it's duration from outside the function.

I'm guessing this is a simple problem of scope common for begginers. Maybe regarding the use of the addEventListener?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>X</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            var video_1 = new CustomVideo('0.mp4');
            video_1.createVideo();

            var videoDuration = video_1.durationVideo();
            console.log('durationVideo outside function = ' + videoDuration);
            });

            function CustomVideo(videoSrc){

                    this.videoSrc = videoSrc;
                    this.createVideo = createVideo;
                    this.durationVideo = durationVideo;

                    var myVideo;
                    var id_rand;
                    var id_myVideo;

                    function createVideo(){
                            myVideo = document.createElement('video');
                            id_rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999);
                            id_myVideo = 'myVideo' + String(id_rand);
                            document.body.appendChild(myVideo);
                            myVideo.id = id_myVideo;
                            myVideo.src = videoSrc;

                    }

                    function durationVideo(){

            console.log('id_myVideo inside durationVideo =' + id_myVideo);
            var v = document.getElementById(id_myVideo);
            v.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function (e) {

                console.log('durationVideo inside func = ' + v.duration);
                return v.duration;

            }, false );
                    }
            }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect to get the duration of the video by evaluating the durationVideo function.

Answer (score 0):

1- Your element should return this html structure :
[Duration Example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_duration)

```
  <video>
       <source src="0.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Comment: I don't know how to do this. I've tried via the createElement and the appendChild functions but I haven't been able. Anyway, the duration gets calculated fine in the second console.log (inside the durationVideo function) it's just I cannot return it correctly when trying to use it elsewhere.